# Get the maximum value from row and insert in one sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, spring-data

I have got following columns in my table feedTable

```
FirstName
LastName
FeedDate
```

I have got below rows in my table

```
XYZ, XYZ, '2021-10-15'
ABC, ABC, '2021-10-16'
ANA, ANA, '2021-10-15'
ALO, ALO, '2021-10-16'
PAIO, PAIO, '2021-10-16'
```

Now I want to insert a record with first name, lastname and maximum date from existing records. It should be in same query. I don't want to use two operation where I need to get maximum date and then insert. What could be the best way to perform this operation?

```
Insert into feedtable (FirstName, LastName, FeedDate) values ('Rahul','B',?)
```

Here In place of '?' I wanted to place maximum date from feeddate. How is it possible?

Please help

Comment: which version of mysql you usse? you'll input firstname and last name. Then combine it with existing max date. Right

Comment: Also _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: Insert into feedtable (FirstName, LastName, FeedDate) values ('Rahul','B',?) Here In place of '?' I wanted to place maximum date from feeddate. How is it possible?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the information you added as a comment to allow all the information needed in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this where first name and last name is input and date is max date from existing table record.

```
INSERT INTO feedTable (FirstName, LastName, FeedDate)
SELECT 'Rahul' FirstName
     , 'B' LastName
     , MAX(FeedDate) FeedDate
FROM feedTable
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1a3ffbc0c701843f7eabf23e40c1d49c

Comment: Insert into feedtable (FirstName, LastName, FeedDate) values ('Rahul','B',?) Here In place of '?' I wanted to place maximum date from feeddate. How is it possible?

Comment: Please check this query.

Answer (score 0):

Solution #1 (For SQL Server)

```
  CREATE TABLE feedTable (
    FirstName varchar(50),
    LastName varchar(50),
    FeedDate  date);

--Date format MM/dd/yyyy
INSERT INTO feedTable VALUES( 'Shohag', 'Mia', '3/31/2021')
INSERT INTO feedTable VALUES( 'Raju', 'Ahmed', '4/6/2021')
INSERT INTO feedTable VALUES( 'Robin', 'Mia', '4/10/2021')
INSERT INTO feedTable VALUES( 'Emon', 'Paki', '12/8/2021')
INSERT INTO feedTable VALUES( 'Saiful', 'Haque', '3/1/2021')

--for checking current max value
SELECT * FROM feedTable ORDER BY FeedDate

--Inserting into main table after selecting max data
INSERT INTO  feedTable 
SELECT FirstName, LastName,FeedDate
FROM feedTable
Where FeedDate =  (SELECT MAX(FeedDate) FROM feedTable)

--for checking value after inserting
SELECT * FROM feedTable ORDER BY FeedDate
```

Or possible second option could be according to your requirement:

```
Insert into feedtable (FirstName, LastName, FeedDate) values ('Rahul','B', (select MAX(FeedDate) from feedTable) )
```

[SQL Fiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3a6597/1/0)

Solution # 2 (For MySql)

```
insert into feedTable select 'Pradeep', '2', MAX(FeedDate) from feedTable
```

[MySql Fiddle Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7677ccf23888762e81ebbb66d7ac4477)

Comment: Insert into feedtable (FirstName, LastName, FeedDate) values ('Rahul','B',?) Here In place of '?' I wanted to place maximum date from feeddate. How is it possible?

Comment: @Rahul please check the updated answer if that meets your requirement

Comment: So having this subquery and having two saperate query,  is thery any performance difference?

Comment: @Rahul it depends, though in this case, I didn't check the Query execution plan, you can obviously check [execution plan](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sql-query-execution-plan/) according to your data volume.

Comment: Okay, Also above Query is possible with the join?

Comment: You meant you want to get the date by joining with some other table?

Comment: No, By joining with the same table. I mean is it possible and logical?

Comment: Also I am getting "You can't specify target table 'feedTable' for update in FROM clause "  When I am running your second option query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238422/discussion-between-tba-and-rahul).